# Is it possible to use Selenium to fetch page source, then use lxml to scrape data by xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, lxml

Selenium can be used to navigate a web site (login, get html source of a page on the site),

but then there is nothing in Selenium that will find/get data in that HTML by `xpath` (`find_element_by_xpath()` will find elements, but not TEXT data outside of tags, and therefore something else must be used like `lxml`), Selenium absolutely cannot be used to do this, as when you try, it throws an error.

---

There are no examples anywhere of using Selenium to get the HTML source, passing that to lxml to parse the HTML and find / get data by xpath anywhere on the web.
It is not to be found.

lxml examples are usually given in conjunction with the Python 'requests' library from which the response in bytes (response.content) is obtained.

lxml uses this `response.content` (bytes), but with lxml, no functions accept the HTML as a string.

Selenium only returns html as a string:  `self.driver.page_source`

So what to do here?

---

I need to use lxml, because it provides xpath capability.

I cannot use Python's requests library to login to a web site and navigate to a page, it just does not work with this site because of some complexities of how they designed things.

Selenium is the only thing that will work to login, create a session, pass the right cookies on a subsequent GET request.

I need to use selenium and 'page_source' (string), but I am not sure how to convert to the exact 'bytes' that the functions 'lxml' requires.

---

It's proving quite difficult to scrape using Python with the way the libraries here do not work together and lack of options with Selenium to produce the HTML as bytes,

and the lack of lxml to accept data either as string or bytes.

---

any and all help would be appreciated, but I don't believe it can be answered unless you have specifically experienced this problem, and have successfully used Selenium + lxml together.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to get page source and then use lxml. Use 'driver.page_source' to get html.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines and see if it works for you:

```
data = self.driver.page_source
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
target = doc.xpath('some xpath')
```